# AngularJS view not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flask

I started learning AngularJS and trying to make a very simple skeleton application with multiple views. I am using Flask for the back-end.

**Problem:** When I load the page it does not show the appropriate view - I get a blank page.

The relevant folder structure is like this:

```
app/
|   static/
|   |      js/
|   |      |  app.js
|   |      |  controllers.js
|   |      partials/
|   |      |        landing.html
|   templates/
|   |         index.html
|   views/
|   |     views.py
```

Basically my `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My App</title>

    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='semantic/semantic.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='semantic/semantic.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/controllers.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My python index function:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return make_response(render_template('index.html'))
```

My 'app.js':

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'static/partials/landing.html',
                    controller: IndexController
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }]);
```

And my `IndexController` in `controllers.js` which does nothing:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

function IndexController($scope) {

}
```

The `landing.html` file simply contains some text.

Where am I going wrong with this? All I get is an empty page. I noticed it does not complain or throw any errors if I put any path in `templateUrl: path/to/landing.html`, so I am not sure this is the correct way reference these files. Is it possible to somehow use the flask `url_for` function here?

**EDIT**

I tried using a template directly instead of a template URL. So I have

```
.....
.when('/', {
             template: 'Hello',
             controller: IndexController
           })
 ....
```

This is still giving me a blank page.

Comment: I don't have that much python knowledge, but what happends when you disable html5mode and use hashbang? $locationProvider.html5Mode(false); when using html5 mode the backend needs to redirect all request to the angular page (except for the views html pages).

Comment: @erik Same thing - blank page

Comment: Open your dev-console and check if all network requests work properly. Maybe you need to serve static files differently or access them differently.

Comment: do you register your controller somewhere? like var app = angular.module('app',[]); app.controller('controllerName', controllerFunction);

Comment: @erik Actually I didn't :). I added the registration but I still get the same results ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your ng-app to your body tag, like this:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My App</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
        <div id="content" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Register module

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.title = "Home Page";
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller : 'IndexController',
            templateUrl : 'landing.html'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/'
        });
}]);
```

Then it should works, angular was now looking inside the head tag for ng-view, but it isn't there. Another option is to put it on the html tag.

Comment: Thank you man! Sometimes simple things get you when you try to learn new tings.